# Converting class component to functional component Props in Functional component not passing properly and Query not being received

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

Hey I am trying to covert a class component into a functional component and for some reason the props I'm passing into the form component are being passed as object values. The original class component works fine but I am not sure what is causing this issue with props. what it looks like with

what it should look like with class component:

[image: function component output]

what I currently have with functional component:

[image: class component output]

function component home page

```
import React from "react";
// import Jumbotron from "react-bootstrap/Jumbotron";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Card from "../components/Card";
import Form from "../components/Form";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Jumbotron from "react-bootstrap/Jumbotron";
import { useState } from "react";
import API from "../utils/API";
import Book from "../components/Book";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import { List } from "../components/List";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import "./style.css";

export default function Home() {
  let [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  let [q, setQ] = useState("");
  let [message, setMessage] = useState("Search For A Book to Begin");

  // const handleInputChange = (event) => {
  //   let { name, value } = event.target;
  //   setQ(([name] = value));
  // };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setQ(event.target.value)
  };

  let getBooks = () => {
    API.getBooks(q)
      .then((res) => setBooks(res.data))
      .catch(() => setBooks([]));
    setMessage("No New Books Found, Try a Different Query");
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    getBooks();
  };

  let handleBookSave = (id) => {
    const book = books.find((book) => book.id === id);

    API.saveBook({
      googleId: book.id,
      title: book.volumeInfo.title,
      subtitle: book.volumeInfo.subtitle,
      link: book.volumeInfo.infoLink,
      authors: book.volumeInfo.authors,
      description: book.volumeInfo.description,
      image: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
    }).then(() => getBooks());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col md={12}>
            <Jumbotron className="rounded-3 mt-4">
              <h1 className="text-center ">
                <strong>(React) Google Books Search</strong>
              </h1>
              <h2 className="text-center">
                Search for and Save Books of Interest.
              </h2>
            </Jumbotron>
          </Col>
          <Col md={12}>
            <Card title="Book Search" icon=" fa-book">
              <Form
                handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
                handleFormSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
                q={q}
              />
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col md={12}>
            <Card title="Results">
              {books.length ? (
                <List>
                  {books.map((book) => (
                    <Book
                      key={book.id}
                      title={book.volumeInfo.title}
                      subtitle={book.volumeInfo.subtitle}
                      link={book.volumeInfo.infolink}
                      authors={book.volumeInfo.authors.join(", ")}
                      description={book.volumeInfo.description}
                      image={book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}
                      Btn={() => (
                        <Button
                          onClick={() => handleBookSave(book.id)}
                          variant="primary"
                          className="ml-2"
                        >
                          Save
                        </Button>
                      )}
                    />
                  ))}
                </List>
              ) : (
                <h2 className="text-center">{message}</h2>
              )}
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Footer />
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Form component

```
import React from "react";
function Formmy({q, handleInputChange, handleFormSubmit }) {
  return (
    <form>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Query">
          <strong>Book</strong>
        </label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          id="Title"
          type="text"
          value={q}
          placeholder="Ready Player One"
          name="q"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div className="float-end">
        <button
          onClick={handleFormSubmit}
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn-lg btn-danger float-right"
        >
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
export default Formmy;
```

Comment: It looks like you're passing all the props to `Form` properly. What exact problem are you experiencing? Handlers not being called? An error when the handlers are called? Something else?

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error for the request but every is set up properly in my controllers and in my utilities. the only thing that is throwing me off is that the "q" from my handlers is being included in my request and  I don't know why http://localhost:3000/api/google?q=title:green+eggs+and+ham

Comment: Which request is giving the 404? The API call? Have you checked the console for errors? If you're calling `e.preventDefault()`, that should prevent the form from submitting, which means you shouldn't get anything in the query string.

Comment: the Api call is giving the error. I did call e.preventDefault

Comment: What error specifically is the API giving? Is the problem that `q` is empty? We really need more details to help you here.